# Use of copy in reindex and saving the newly indexed data

Tags: python, pandas

**I have the following code:**

```
dat = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4), index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
dat.reindex(['b', 'c', 'a', 'd'])
dat
```

However, when I view `dat`, it still has the index as `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. To save `dat` with the new index, do I have only

```
dat = dat.reindex(['b', 'c', 'a', 'd'])
```

as the option? Or is there another way?

Also, when I run the following:

```
dat.reindex(['b', 'c', 'a', 'd'], copy = False)
```

it still shows the same index `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. I don't understand the use of the *copy* parameter?

Comment: `copy = False` is not equal to `inplace=true`, therefore to retain your order you'll still need to re-assign back to dat fo the second issue you raised.  For the first, issue.  Is there a problem with using reindex?  You could use .loc like this `dat.loc[['b','c','a','d'],:]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the result to access it. Some functions in `pandas` take an `inplace=True` parameter but reindex does not.

```
dat = dat.reindex(['b', 'c', 'a', 'd'])
```

---

To understand the use of the copy parameter, compare:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4), index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
x = dat.reindex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], copy=True)
x.iloc[0,0] += 1
```

with

```
dat = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4), index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
x = dat.reindex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], copy=False)
x.iloc[0,0] += 1
```

Comment: so it means that any change in x changes the original 'dat' data set. That's the only use of copy as False?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You can also use the `.copy()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .loc like this instead of reindex (see comments below, best to use reindex):

```
dat.loc[['b','c','a','d'],:]
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D
b   4   5   6   7
c   8   9  10  11
a   0   1   2   3
d  12  13  14  15
```

Comment: Rather not, test `dat.loc[['b','c','a','d', 'sss'],:]`

Comment: @jezrael does reaise a great point, re-index will populate NaN for non-existant keys, where loc will return Key Error.  Is best to use `reindex`.

Comment: Just test it, maybe in newer version of pandas it working, but I remember some problem with not exist values (maybe bug in some old versions of pandas, not sure)

Comment: {/home/scott/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1472: FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.} in pandas 0.23.0